# Proving that $h$ is an automorphism if $2h^2+4h+2I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I dont know how i can solve this problem. You have one vector space $V$ with a linear transformation: $h: V \to  V$. So we have an endomorphism.  The question is to show that if $h$ satisfies $2h^2+4h+2I=0$, where I is the identity transformation and 0 is the null transformation, then $h$ is an automorphism. Why? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**

If $2 h^2 + 4h +2I=0$ then $h(-h-2h)=I$

Comment: i dont know, what happens if h(-h-2h)=I

Comment: Note $k=-h-2h$. You have $hk=kh=I$. So $k$ is the inverse of $h$.

Comment: $H$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is **invertible**.

Comment: Oh god, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a finite dimensional space, an endomorphism is an automorphism if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue. Now, the only eigenvalue is $-1$ since the eigenvalues are the roots of the *minimal polynomial* of $h$ and  $2t^2+4t+2=2(t+1)^2$, which is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, has only one root, $-1$.